# PostgreSQL: Where does the output of ereport() go?

Tags: postgresql

I am in the middle of developing a C extension library for PostgreSQL. I am using a lot of ereport() calls to help with future debugging.

A typical example of usage in my code would be something like this:

```
ereport(NOTICE, (errmsg("[%s]: Returned nonzero result (%d).", (const char*)__FUNCTION__, ret)) );
```

However, when I look in /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-8.4-main.log my messages do not seem to be appearing there - only messages from what I assume is the db server daemon.

So, where are my log messages being stored?

BTW, I am running PG 8.4 on Ubuntu Linux (10.0.4)

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, logging of non-critical messages is not enabled on fresh installs. You configure it by setting `log_destination` and `logging_collector`.

PostgreSQL has several logging levels, and by default, `NOTICE` level is not saved to log files (even when they are enabled) . This is configured by `log_min_messages` setting. However `NOTICE` it emitted to client by default. This is configured by `client_min_messages` setting.

So if you want these to be stored in log files, you will have to either change `NOTICE` to `WARNING` in your code, or set `log_min_messages = notice`.

See this http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-logging.html
and maybe this http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/05/06/understanding-postgresql-conf-log/